# Passing Enums as a Float

Tags: c++, enums

I have a question concerning enumerations and floats.
I'm trying to pass an enum as a float is this possible?

Here's an outline of the code:

```
enum
{
    none = 0,
    small,
    medium,
    large, 
} enumSize;

class size
{
    float footsize = 0.0; 
}

void setSize(size &Size, float value)
{
    Size.footsize = value; 
}

int main()
{ 
    size Size; 
    setSize(Size, enumSize); 
}
```

However I cannot call setSize(Size, enumSize) since as far as I know enums can only be ints and cant be casted to be a float?  If that's the case is there a way to make it a float with my current setup?

If my layout is slightly confusing let me know and I'll try to address any confusion best I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course ints can be cast to floats, but an enum is not an appropriate tool for this.  Just use `const float`s.

By the way, your code doesn't compile for several other reasons as well.

Comment: I know that's not my exact code, its much more convoluted than the above, but the above is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I agree with this approach. Where you put the `const float`s would depend highly on the API structure -- should a `Size` object know about small, medium, and large values, or should that be handled by some other intermediary? If the latter, you might put each float as a static member of a `CommonSizeValues` class. Yes, that's a very Java/C# way to do it, but it would work without having to deal with messy namespacing issues.

Comment: All is well until somewhere you call `setSize(mySize, 3.14159);` unless you _expect_ your `footSize` to be the integer value `3` instead of float value `PI`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no casting involved, just a conversion. Ordinary enums are integer values and when you pass one of them to a function that takes a float the value gets converted to float.

```
enum enumSize {
    none,
    small,
    medium,
    large
};

void f(float);

void g() {
    f(small);
}
```